# How can I stop image indentation exceeding beyond its container margin?

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs

I have an image editor where i can upload image from my local machine.

By default uploaded image is left align. Now if i try to right indent that image, it goes beyond editor boundary area.

I need to stop this image indent before editor margin.

How can I resolve this problem using CSS?

[here is a screen capture of my problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Sv452.jpg).
Thanks in advance

Comment: may I suggest you give us a code sample? that way, we will be able to pinpoint the problem and therefore give a better answer to your question